# <g:set> variable's value is not being rendered properly

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

I've used `<g:set>` tag like this:

```
<g:set var="extraStyle" value="style='min-width:120px;'"/>
```

and used the `extraStyle` variable like this:

```
<div class="myClass" ${extraStyle}> ${myValue}</div>
```

---

And it should be rendered as:

```
<div class="myClass" style="min-width:120px;"> XYZ </div>
```

But, I am getting this instead:

```
<div class="myClass" style="'min-width:120px;'"> XYZ </div>
```

Due to which, min-width style is not being applied. What am I doing wrong here?

**Grails version: 3.1.6**

Comment: escape the `'`: `<g:set var="extraStyle" value="style=\'min-width:120px;\'"/>`

Comment: what happening if you remove the single quote. value="style=min-width:120px;"

Comment: @Djamware surprisingly, removing the single quote worked. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try just setting the style value e.g.

```
<g:set var="extraStyle" value="min-width:120px;"/>

<div class="myClass" style="${extraStyle}"> ${myValue}</div>
```

Comment: This works but, if I had to use conditions, this would fail. For example, for some condition if I don't want the `'min-width=120px'` the div would be rendered as: `<div class="myClass" style> XYZ </div>`. Anyway thanks for the solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think Mike's answer is correct, and although I do not know the context of your project I think it might in the long run be better to add a class dynamically to the element.

Something like

```
<div class="myClass ${extraClass}">...</div>
```